# Make POST API method correctly handle simultaneous requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So let's imagine there's some entity called "Products" and you have the REST API including POST that creates the product. The Product has an "ID" field which is auto-generated and unique "Name" field. What yo do inside the method is:

1. Validate that there's no other product with the same name. So you select the product from the DB and compare the Name with the input parameter
2. If there's already created the same product - you return 400
3. if there's no products with the specified name - you create the entity and save it to the DB

The problem is if there's 2 simultaneous POST requests, you will get an error. Should we use some locking mechanism here? How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use locking of any sort really, use a [unique constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on the name field, this will stop you being able to store two products with the same name. Then catch the exception thrown and return it as 400.

Keep the rest of your method logic the same, I'm guessing this is a very edge case and the chances of two requests actually happening at the same moment are really small. 99.999% of the time your validation will catch this.

Comment: This makes sense. The Name already added to the unique constraint. I just wanted to find the other way in order to let my validation handle this and not produce the exceptions. There are cases where this scenario is very common